# Cannot migrate on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, migrate

I'd like to migrate database to production environment on Heroku.

I typed the following code, however I got error. I have no idea what to do. I'm looking forward to your advice. Thank you for your kindness.

```
$ heroku run rake db:migrate

Running `rake db:migrate --trace` attached to terminal... up, run.2338
rake aborted!
LoadError: libruby.so.2.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/pg-0.18.2/lib/pg_ext.so
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/pg-0.18.2/lib/pg.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
/app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/app/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/app/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:689:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/app/bin/rake:8:in `<main>'
```

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31615921/heroku-loaderror-libruby-so-2-2 could help you.

Comment: Dear Pavan
I tried that before, but it could not solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried running migration directly from the bash inside the heroku server? If not, try the following...

```
heroku run bash --app your_app_name_goes_here
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

First line of code opens the bash command terminal and the second one migrates the db as usual.

---

This would not be the suggested solution. But, in case you DO NOT care about losing data in the database, you can try and reset the database first and try again. Again, don't do this unless you are willing to lose existing data!

```
heroku pg:reset DATABASE
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

However you can perform this via bash as before.

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: Thank you!
I tried both of your advices, however it returned the same error.

LoadError: libruby.so.2.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/pg-0.18.2/lib/pg_ext.so

Comment: Hmm seems like a problem with Postgres. Try running  `gem install pg --pre` and try again. This installs the pre release version.

Comment: It seems that "gem install pg --pre" cannot solve the problem either.
Anyway thank your for your help!

Comment: Ah what a shame yomihito. I hope you find the solution quickly

Comment: DearTim
I've solved the problem.
At gemfile, I've set past version of 'pg' as following.Before that I didn't set version of 'pg'

[Before]
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

[After]
group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

Comment: Thank you for your kindness!!^^

Answer (score 1):

You can run a dyno in the background using `heroku run:detached`. Unlike heroku run, these dynos will send their output to your logs instead of your console window. You can use heroku logs to view the output from these commands:
`$ heroku run:detached rake db:migrate
Running rake db:migrate... up, run.2
Use 'heroku logs -p run.2' to view the log output.`