# Heroku rails pg_ext.so LoadError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, pg

I am  trying to deploy my rails app to Heroku. I've created an app and successfully pushed it, but when i do

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

i am getting this error

```
>     rake aborted!
>     LoadError: libruby.so.2.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory -
> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.21.0/lib/pg_ext.so
```

Rails 5.0.4
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]
pg-0.21.0

I've seen similar posts and tried to apply described solutions, but no luck. Tried other versions of pg like here [Cannot migrate on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31780627/cannot-migrate-on-heroku)
But it didn't help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try [purging Heroku dyno's cache](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-repo):

```
heroku plugins:install https://github.com/heroku/heroku-repo.git
heroku repo:purge_cache -a appname
```

Comment: As i understood the proper comand is "heroku plugins:install heroku-repo" and then "heroku repo:purge_cache -a myappname". Did it and the cache is clered, but same error still remains.