# "error while loading shared libraries: libruby.so.2.5" while pushing previously working Ruby/Rails app to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a Ruby on Rails application hosted on Heroku, which has previously been working. I made a small modification to the project (controller and view code only, no changes to the configuration settings) and when I try to push to Heroku, it fails with an `error while loading shared libraries: libruby.so.2.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. The whole output of the git push:

```
Quesadilla:portfolio paulbogard$ git push heroku
Counting objects: 11, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (11/11), done.
Writing objects: 100% (11/11), 1.24 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 11 (delta 9), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Deleting 1 files matching .slugignore patterns.
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/vendor/ruby/heroku-16/bin/ruby: error while loading shared libraries: libruby.so.2.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to pb-portfolio.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/pb-portfolio.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/pb-portfolio.git'
```

I tried purging the cache in the heroku dyno as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31624064/1151015), but I continue to get the same error.

The application works as expected on my development device, I just can't push it to Heroku.

How can I have Heroku find the library it claims to be missing?

Comment: File a support request with Heroku. It shouldn't do that. Try to push again - maybe that particular Dyno is corrupted? Try to set the Ruby version to `2.5.3` or `~>2.4` to get a different Ruby version. Heroku recently made some changes to their stack and I also ran into a different problem with builds recently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the issue had to do with me being connected to a public WiFi hotspot when I pushed to Heroku; when I tethered my laptop to my phone for internet access, the push succeeded.

For some reason I’d assumed the source would be compiled on Heroku’s end, but apparently it’s compiled locally, and the public hotspot must have been blocking access to the location of the library.

Comment: I came here from Google. I don't think this was WiFi, not that it matters now: https://status.heroku.com/incidents/1695